# How do I change the 'From' value of mail failure items?

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm exporting/extracting mail failure items located in a subfolder named 'Subfolder' to a local folder on my laptop using this Outlook code:

```
Private Sub DBC1()

Set inbox = Session.GetDefaultFolder(6).Folders("Subfolder")

For Each m In inbox.Items
    intCount = m.Attachments.Count
    If intCount > 0 Then
        For i = 1 To intCount
            m.Attachments.Item(i).SaveAsFile "C:\info\" & _
                m.Attachments.Item(i).FileName
        Next
    End If
    Next

End Sub
```

I need to change the sender address. How do I change the 'From' value?

Comment: Do you mean change the sender related properties in the saved MSG file but not in the original email?

Comment: Correct. I will need to move these to another tenant and send from there using the new 'FROM' address. However, if I have a script that changed the sender in the original email, that would work too and could run it first. Then I could then run my script above and export that way too.

Answer (score 0):

Even though you can open an MSG file using `Namespace.OpenSharedItem`, Outlook Object Model will not let you modify the sender related properties using `MailItem.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty` (it likes being the Big Brother who knows best).

If using [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author) is an option, you can use [RDOSession](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdosession.htm).`GetMessageFromMsgFile` to open an MSG file (returns [RDOMail](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOMail.htm) object), then either wipe out the sender setting `RDOMail.Sender` / `SentOnBehalfOf` to Nothing (null) or set them to a valid [RDOAddressEntry](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOAddressEntry.htm) object.